# Dynamically declaring TextViews

Tags: java, android, memory

I'm trying to create an Android memo application for learning purposes. I store all my memos in `final TextView[] notes = new TextView[200];`
Here, I realise I'll have to have a cap on number of memos which currently is 200. Another option could be of storing the notes in a string array. Regardless, one option is to keep an if condition which checks whenever the number of notes becomes the size of the array, create another array of `size = size+1` and copy the contents of the previous array. Is there a better way of doing this? Also, how do I calculate the size one TextView variable takes. I ask this whether I should be thinking of deleting the previous array as I make a new one. Will doing `notes = null;` do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a master in android, in these conditions mentioned by you i would use a ListView and will keep updating the list for every new memo and list will be keep growing.

Comment: Even then I'd have to store the data in a string array which is memory bound.

Comment: What i understand is that you want to display all the memo and have a copy of it , why do you have to store it in a array, you can display it in a ListView. If you want the data to remain  after the app is closed so that you can show the memo once app is started again , you can save the contents of the listview in to a file on the OnDestroy function of thee app.

Comment: The 200 TextViews at once would be a far larger issue than an array of 200 Strings.  Use an ArrayList<String> or a db to store your memos.

Answer (score 1):

On UI, use a `ListView` because `ListView` recycles the views that are not visible on screen, creating 200+ `TextView`'s in code is a bad practice.

You can use `SQLite` database to store all your memos but read **only** N number of memos say 10 at a time from database and display them on screen.

In general, it is fine to use [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) but keep N number of items at a time in it that were read from database, use its `clear()` and `add()` methods to replace old items with the new ones.

[Android's documentation about LinkedList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> This class is primarily useful if you need queue-like behavior. It may
>   also be useful as a list if you expect your lists to contain zero or
>   one element, but still require the ability to scale to slightly larger
>   numbers of elements. In general, though, you should probably use
>   ArrayList if you don't need the queue-like behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As for the array of notes increasing in size, doing size=size+1 is generally bad, since you have to reinitialize a whole array each time you add a memo. Rather, when you reach maximum, double the array size, and when the array is a quarter full, halve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a data structure for keeping the memos choose a [LinkedList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList.html). The benefit is there is no resizing and copying of the data needed. Because a LinkedList uses no array to save the data, like e.g. an ArrayList. The list can grow as long memory is available.

A LinkedList would be ok for your learning curve. But you will end up with a SQLite database to persist the memos if your App will be destroyed by the system f.e.